# Is it Possible to View Microsoft VBA Code for Their Standard Excel Formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating several User Defined Functions (UDF's). I'm proficient enough that I can write *most* of the code on my own. However, there are some situations where I am interested in seeing how Microsoft handles inputs, defends against errors, and optimizes performance. **Does anyone know where I could find the exact Visual Basic syntax that Microsoft uses to write their standard Excel formulas?**

To illustrate, below is a UDF I have created to mimic Vlookup and I'd like to compare it to Microsoft's function. For example, how does Microsoft's code analyze the first column? Does it use a cell loop or a Match function? How does it handle errors?

```
Public Function VLookupPGCodeRider(TextInput As String, SearchRange As Range, _
ColumnIndex As Integer, PartialMatch As Boolean) As String
Dim WS As Worksheet, Rcell As Range
Set WS = Sheets(SearchRange.Parent.Name)

On Error GoTo BadResult
If TextInput = "" Or SearchRange Is Nothing Or Not (IsNumeric(ColumnIndex)) Then
GoTo BadResult
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'I would like to see how MS sets up this loop, or maybe they use match?
'But then how does match work??
For Each Rcell In Intersect(SearchRange.Columns(1), WS.UsedRange).Cells

    If Not (PartialMatch) Then 'how 99.9% of users use Vlookup
        If Rcell.Value = TextInput Then
            VLookupPGCodeRider = Intersect(Rcell.EntireRow, SearchRange.Columns(ColumnIndex)).Value
            Exit Function
        End If

    Else
        'what is considered a partial match??
    End If

Next Rcell

'if nothing found or error in the beginning of formula...
BadResult:
VLookupPGCodeRider = "#NA"

End Function
```

Again, I'm not looking for answers to Vlookup specifically, I just want to see Microsofts' method to handling similar formula challenges I'm facing with a variety of my UDF's.

I have checked in the Excel VBA Object Browser (2013) and I see the below screenshot, which is not very helpful. When I look through my Excel installation folder, I'm not finding anything that corresponds with the naming structure of the worksheetfunction.

I suppose it's possible that MS intentionally does not want to share this information, which would be disappointing, but I'd appreciate confirmation if anyone is certain.

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK Vba sources are kept proprietary by Microsoft and are not publicly available

Comment: `Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` is not written in VBA.  It would be written in something like C++.  Just as the `VLOOKUP` functionality used by a formula in Excel itself would be.

Comment: Shoot Thanks for feedback, I'm marking as helpful. I figured that to be the case but I thought it might be easy to work around like worksheet or VBA protection. Maybe someone knows of a way, so I'll keep question up a bit longer.

Comment: @YowE3K well, there's the answer! Want a free upvote?

Comment: If someone puts that as the answer, and nobody else comes up with a way around, then yes, I'll mark as answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for `Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, etc, is not written in VBA. It would be written in something like C++. Just as the `VLOOKUP` functionality used by a formula in Excel itself would be.

Comment: Dang. I thought it might be in VB.net or something that I could leverage. C++ won't help unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug. Indeed this is in relation to COM add-on, so actually, your GitHub effort may get cloned!! Thanks for chiming in.